# Disable NSButton when multiple items selected - Cocoa Bindings

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-bindings, appkit

I'd like to disable a NSButton when multiple items are selected in a `NSTableView` which is connected to a `NSArrayController`. I know I can easily disable a button when nothing is selected (binding to `@count`), but I'm not sure how to reverse that so that `@count` has to be == 1 to be enabled.

I am using Swift, but I'm more interested in the best method than a language specific implementation (unless the difference between Swift and Objective C is a big one in this instance).

How can I use Cocoa Bindings to disable a `NSButton` if the selection includes more than one row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your existing binding binds your button's *enabled* binding to your array controller's *selectionIndexes* property, you can achieve what you're after with a value transformer:

[image]

The button's state will be updated any time there's a change to the array controller's *selectionIndexes* property. Part of this update will involve a call to your value transformer, where the incoming value will be the updated *selectionIndexes*. Your transformer logic must *transform* this object into a boolean (enabled, or not-enabled), which will in turn determine the state of the button:

```
@objc(SelectionIndexesCountIsOneOrZeroTransformer)
public class SelectionIndexesCountIsOneOrZeroTransformer): NSValueTransformer {

    override public class func allowsReverseTransformation() -> Bool {
        return false
    }

    override public class func transformedValueClass() -> AnyClass {
        return NSNumber.self
    }

    override public func transformedValue(value: AnyObject?) -> AnyObject? {
        var retval = false

        if let indexSet = value as? NSIndexSet {
            retval = (indexSet.count < 2)
        }

        return retval
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was after (I wanted to avoid subclassing my `NSTableView`). I think I understand what is going on, but why do I need the `@objc` keyword? Is it because Cocoa Bindings expect `NSValueTransformer` to be available in ObjC, not Swift?

Comment: I don't know exactly what the ``@objc`` keyword does, but yes it's a Swift/Objective-C compatibility thing. At least when Swift first came out, value transformers written in Swift and referenced in Interface Builder didn't work without this keyword.

Comment: Ah ok. If I take it out then I get an exception saying the value transformer can't be found, so that certainly still seems to be the case.

Comment: Brilliant. I like this solution. I was also easily able to modify this to return true if `count > 0`. Note for Swift 4, the syntax has changed. `NSValueTransformer` becomes `ValueTransformer` and `transformedValue(value: AnyObject?) -> AnyObject?` becomes `transformedValue(_ value: Any?) -> Any?`

Answer (score 4):

- We assume that the class containing the table view is called `tableViewController`
- Declare a property `selectionIndexes` in `tableViewController`.

  Objective-C:

  ```
  @property NSIndexSet *selectionIndexes;
  ```

  Swift:

  ```
  dynamic var selectionIndexes = NSIndexSet()
  ```
- Bind `Selection Indexes` of the table view to that property.
- In `tableViewController` add these two methods

  Objective-C:

  ```
  + (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingEnableButton
  {
    return [NSSet setWithObject:@"selectionIndexes"];
  }

  - (BOOL)enableButton
  {
    return self.selectionIndexes.count < 2;
  }
  ```

  Swift:

  ```
  override class func keyPathsForValuesAffectingEnableButton(key : String) -> Set<String> {
       return Set<String>(["selectionIndexes"])
  }

  func enableButton() -> Bool
  {
    return selectionIndexes.count < 2
  }
  ```

  `keyPathsForValuesAffecting<key>` is a method to easily implement a key-value observer.
- Now bind the `Enabled` property of the button to `enableButton` of `tableViewController`.

If you are using an array controller, bind `Selection Indexes` of the table view to `selectionIndexes` of the array controller and `Selection Indexes` of the array controller to `selectionIndexes` of `tableViewController`.

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to keep it language agnostic, since it's more about how to do the binding correctly than implement it (I'm using Swift but that's easy to convert). I'm surprised the solution doesn't involved my `NSArrayController`..? (maybe my question was too vague)!